# Why does it keep returning false positive?

Tags: python, string, loops, if-statement, letter

Why is it that my code keeps returning yes in the code I've written?

```
def alphaToPhone(alpha):
    for i in range(len(alpha)):
        if i=="b" or "k" or "c":
            phone="yes"
        else:
            phone="no"
    return phone

print(alphaToPhone("23ht"))
```

Comment: this question has been asked soooo many times...

Comment: ! remove `range(len` from `range(len(alpha))`, becouse range(len(alpha)) = [1,2,3,4] for alpha = "23ht"

Comment: Because you're short circuiting the `or` operator, the statement `1 == "b" or "k" or "c"`
results in `'k'` as the first value is falsey

Answer (score 7):

Because non-empty strings evaluate to `True` in Python. Solution for you problem could be one of the following

```
if i=="b" or i == "k" or i == "c":
```

or

```
if i in ["b", "k", "c"]:
```

Apart from that you are iterating over a wrong set of values. Replace your `for` with

```
for i in alpha:
```

Comment: He iterates in range. You are comparing index with letters.

Comment: Yep, that's wrong too - `for i in alpha:` would be better.

Answer (score 3):

You have missed the check

```
  def alphaToPhone(alpha):
        for i in alpha:
            if i == "b" or i == "k" or i == "c":
                phone="yes"
            else:
                phone="no"
        return phone

  print(alphaToPhone("23ht"))
```

Comment: He iterates in range. You are comparing index with letters.

Comment: @Nurzhan: I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition `i=="b" or "k" or "c"` probably isn't what you wanted. It always returns true, because `"k"` (and `"c"` as well) is true. What you want is:

```
if i=="b" or i=="k" or i=="c":
```

or, better:

```
if i in {"b", "c", "k"}:
```

Comment: He iterates in range. You are comparing index with letters.

Answer (score 1):

You code should be like this:

```
def alphaToPhone(alpha):
    for ch in alpha:
        if ch == "b" or ch=="k" or ch=="c":
            phone="yes"
        else:
            phone="no"
    return phone

print(alphaToPhone("23ht"))
```